# How to correct this redundancy in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building an app in ionic, and I need to pass items into another array, but when I pass the same item again it's considered the same item - really - but I need that to not happen. I need them to be considered different or or at least be considered different. Each item(is an object) of array have a var `"qntt"(quantity)` and when this bug happen, instead put the same item in array, plus one in this var. OBS: I'm using `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"` in html.

```
<ion-view title="Order">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" style="background: url(img/background1.jpg) no-repeat center;" class="has-header" ng-controller="pedidoCtrl">
    <button class="button button-dark button-small button-block" ng-click="showDelete = !showDelete">Remover</button>
    <ion-list show-delete="showDelete">
        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"></ion-delete-button>
                <img src="{{item.img}}">
                <h2>{{item.nome}}</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-60">
                        <h2>R{{item.subtotal | currency}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-15">
                        <button class="button button-clear button-assertive button-small icon ion-minus" ng-click="subQtt(item)"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-10">
                        <h2>{{item.qtt}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-15">
                        <button class="button button-icon-right button-clear button-assertive button-small icon ion-plus" ng-click="addQtt(item)"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button style="text-align:right;" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-left ion-cash">R{{total | currency}}</button>
    <div style="margin-right:-20px;">
        <button style="left:-10px;" class="button button-dark button-large button-full icon ion-android-cart">Order</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

```
.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, productService) { 
$scope.items = null;
$scope.items = productService.getProducts();

$scope.deleteItem = function(item){
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
};

$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(array) {
     if (array) {
            $scope.total = array.reduce(function(total,item) {
                    return total + item.subtotal;
                },0);
      } 
      $scope.addQtt = function(item){
        item.qtt = item.qtt + 1;
        item.subtotal = item.price * item.qtt;
        $scope.total = array.reduce(function(total,item) {
                    return total + item.subtotal;
                },0);
       };
        $scope.subQtt = function(item){
            if(item.qtt > 1)
            {
                item.qtt--;
                item.subtotal = item.price * item.qtt;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
            }
            $scope.total = array.reduce(function(total,item) {
                    return total + item.subtotal;
                },0);
    }; 
 });

})

.service('productService', [function(){
var productList = [];

var addProduct = function(product) {
    productList.push(product);
};

var getProducts = function(){
    return productsList;
};
return {
    addProduct: addProduct,
    getProducts: getProducts,
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not calling the service method `addProduto()` within your controller. Try calling `produtoService.addProduto()` within the `$scope.addQnt()` method as below and it should work:

```js
$scope.addQnt = function(item){
  item.qntd = item.qntd + 1;
  item.subtotal = item.preco * item.qntd;
  $scope.total = array.reduce(function(total,item) {
    return total + item.subtotal;
  },0);
  
  // Add this line to retain your addition in service
  produtoService.addProduto(item);

  // Get updated list of products
  $scope.items = productoService.getProdutos();
  // Alternatively use '$scope.items.push(item)'
};
```

Also, you need to refresh your `$scope.items` by triggering a call to `productoService.getProdutos()`, though you can do it directly by pushing in `$scope.items.push(item)`

Comment: Doesnt work, I need when add the same item into the list, instead of being considered the same item, plus one in the var qntd of the object or the same item being considered diferent.

Comment: sorry, the I think you change things because of name of my vars, $scope.addQnt this I use to plus one of each object in the var "qntd", if I do what you say, duplicate the items.My native language is not English.

Comment: I am sorry but I am having difficulty understanding your english